# Adding python strip commands into a function

Tags: python

How do I put the following python code into a function

```
    [x.strip('\n') for x in list]
    [x.strip(' ') for x in list]
    [x.strip('\n') for x in list]
```

I have tried the following but it didn't carry out any of the cleanings

```
def cleanup( list ):
    [x.strip('\n') for x in list]
    [x.strip(' ') for x in list]
    [x.strip('\n') for x in list]
    return
```

called via cleanup(horsename)

Comment: You have to actually return something from your function. Your `return` as is is not returning anything right now. It is actually returning `None`. What you should probably do is store that "cleaning" in some var like `res` and then return `res`. Furthermore, do not use variable names like `list` as you are shadowing the built-in `list`.

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to assign `[x.strip('\n') for x in num]` to a variable in one case but not necessary in another?  Hint: Only one of those is correct.

Comment: *"How do I put the following python code into a function"* - but then you put *different* code into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You you could write

```
def cleanup( list ):
    return [x.strip('\n').strip(" ").strip("\n") for x in list]
```

Maybe, you can actually write it shorter (be careful, it's semantically different):

```
def cleanup( list ):
    return [x.strip('\n ') for x in list]
```

This works because `strip` removes all characters in the string from left and right that you pass in the string.

Edit - Semantic difference:

Let's illustrate this with an example:

```
>>> s="\n \n r \n \n"
>>> s.strip('\n').strip(" ").strip("\n")
' r '
>>> s.strip('\n ')
'r'
```

The first version first removes all `\n` from left and right, then from the resulting string all space from left and right, and from that resulting string all `\n`. The second version removes all `\n` and space characters from left and right. If they alternate often enough as in the example, it makes a difference.

Comment: @JonClements: I've added an explanation on the semantic difference.